# How to set default selection for listbox in and select an item with key press?

Tags: vba, outlook, listbox

I have a macro in that creates a ListBox.
[image: the following picture appears]

The first item should be selected as default.
[image: this picture]

I tried

```
UserForm.ListBox.Selected(0) = True
```

I get
[image: empty Listbox]

How can I control the Listbox from the keyboard? I need to scroll up and down with "UP" and "DOWN" keys and if "ENTER" is pressed the selected Item should be taken.

I tried the following, but this captures every "ENTER" during the code (not only when the UserForm (ListBox) is loaded).

```vb
Public Sub Listbox_Enter()
    'DO Something
End Sub
```

Current code:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents GExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Public WithEvents GMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Public WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents objTask As Outlook.TaskItem
        
        
'Start Outlook
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set GExplorer = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set objInspectors = Outlook.Application.Inspectors
End Sub
        
'Capture every change, but on same ActiveExplorer (Window)
Private Sub GExplorer_SelectionChange()
    Dim xItem As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xItem = GExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    If xItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
    Set GMailItem = xItem
End Sub
        
'Reply pressed
Private Sub GMailItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    AutoAddGreetingtoReply Response
End Sub
        
'ReplyAll pressed
Private Sub GMailItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    AutoAddGreetingtoReply Response
End Sub
        
'Forward pressed
Private Sub GMailItem_Forward(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    AutoAddGreetingtoReply Response
End Sub
        
        
Sub AutoAddGreetingtoReply(Item As Object)
    Dim xGreetStr As String:        Dim xReplyMail As MailItem
    Dim xSenderName As String:      Dim lSpace As Long
    Dim xRecipient As Recipient:    Dim obj As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim EmailAdress As String:      Dim EmailNameBeforeAtIkon As String:
    Dim c As ContactItem
    Dim names As String
 
    On Error Resume Next:
    Set obj = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        
    'This part finds the receipients
    If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub 'Quits if no email is chosen
    Set xReplyMail = Item
                    
    For Each xRecipient In xReplyMail.Recipients
        If xSenderName = "" Then
            xSenderName = xRecipient.name
        Else
            xSenderName = xSenderName & ", " & xRecipient.name
        End If
                                
    Next xRecipient
               
    Dim lSpace_f As Variant
    Dim stFirstNAme As String
    Dim st_FirstName As String
    Dim currentNAme As String
                 
    lSpace_f = InStr(1, xSenderName, " ", vbTextCompare)
    If lSpace_f > 0 Then
        stFirstNAme = Trim(Split(xSenderName, ",")(1))
        st_FirstName = Split(stFirstNAme, " ")(0)
        currentNAme = st_FirstName + ","
    End If
                    
    'Writes a greeting
                
    With UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl
        .AddItem "Hello " + currentNAme
        .AddItem "Good morning " + currentNAme
    End With
        
    UserForm1.Caption = ("Greeting")
                
    Load UserForm1
        
    UserForm1.StartUpPosition = 2
    UserForm1.Show
                
    'Creates the email
    With xReplyMail
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><Body><span style=""color:#0e4a80"">" + markierterEintrag + "</span style=""color:#0e4a80""></HTML></Body>" & .HTMLBody
        Sendkeys "{DOWN}", True
        Sendkeys "{ENTER}", True
        Call Sendkeys("", False)
        .Close olSave
    End With
End Sub
        
Public Sub Sendkeys(text As Variant, Optional wait As Boolean = False)
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    WshShell.Sendkeys CStr(text), wait
    Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub

'-------------------------------------
Public Sub Listbox_Auswahl_Click()
    If UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.ListIndex > -1 Then
        markierterEintrag = UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.List(UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.ListIndex)
    End If
            
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
        
'Public Sub Listbox_Auswahl_Enter()
    '    If UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.ListIndex > -1 Then
    '        markierterEintrag = UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.List(UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.ListIndex)
    '    End If
    '
    '    Unload UserForm1
'End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    Public Sub Listbox_Auswahl_Click()
        If UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.ListIndex > -1 Then
            markierterEintrag = UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.List(UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.ListIndex)
        End If

    End Sub


    Public Sub Listbox_Auswahl_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

        If KeyAscii = 13 Then
            With Me.Listbox_Auswahl
                If .ListIndex > -1 Then
                    markierterEintrag = .List(.ListIndex)
                End If
            End With
            Unload UserForm1
        End If
    End Sub


    Public Sub Listbox_Auswahl_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        If Button = 1 Then
            'pressed_key_flag = 1
            If UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.ListIndex > -1 Then
                markierterEintrag = UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.List(UserForm1.Listbox_Auswahl.ListIndex)
                Unload UserForm1
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```